# SQL Query for filtering on 3 conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access, filter

I am new to SQL and I have a MS-Access database where I want to filter all the data on three types of conditions.

- The first condition for the database should be meeting all data in column named "Range-1" which contains:
  "Information Technology".
- The second condition should contain data in column named "Range-2":
  "Cyber Companies" or "Telecommunications" or "Robotics".
- The third condition should contain data in column named "Range-3":
  "Insurance, Tech" or "Fiber, Optics, Silicon Valley" or "MedTech, InsurTech, FinTech, Infra".

The goal should be a query which fits any of the possible combinations - f.e.:
"Information Technology" -> "Telecommunications" -> "MedTech, InsurTech, FinTech, Infra".

The name of the table is `mytable`.

I am thankful for any help. :)

Comment: Your question reads like a coding request.  Can you edit your question and show us sample table data, along with the expected output?

Comment: Hi @KanimeHinyemata please add some code in the question so we can see you have tried something...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for your advice, I will take into account for future questions I should raise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below condition.

```
where Range-1 in ('Information Technology')
and Range-2 in ('Cyber Companies' , 'Telecommunications' , 'Robotics')
and Range-3 in ('Insurance, Tech' , 'Fiber, Optics, Silicon Valley' , 'MedTech, 
InsurTech, FinTech, Infra'.
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it did help!

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access the syntax would look like:

```
select *
from mytable
where [Range-1] in ("Information Technology") and
      [Range-2] in ("Cyber Companies", "Telecommunications", "Robotics") and
      [Range-3] in ("Insurance, Tech", "Fiber, Optics, Silicon Valley", "MedTech, 
InsurTech, FinTech, Infra")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it did help!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . The syntax of the other answer is not suitable for MS Access.